# Vue: only allow access to page if redirected to programatically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a route which shows after a user has completed a payment, say at the `/success` URL. How would I make that someone can't simply go to `example.com/success` and see the success screen. Instead, it should only be accessed by running `this.$router.go('/success/');` in code.

Thanks

Comment: assume you are looking for something like this https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html).

You can add a `beforeEnter` to the route which you can use to check if the user should access the page.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        // ...
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to access vuex state from the beforeEnter method?

Comment: I'm not sure for adding it at VueRouter level. If use [in-component](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) you can access it as normal with `this.$store`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with router navigation guards, in particular [in-component guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards). By defining the `beforeRouteEnter`, you can check (for example) the store, to see if data associated with payments is defined.